# SQL query optimization: take entry with a certain condition, or random entry otherwise

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create an SQL query for SQLite 3 that takes the first value (lowest ID) where a certain condition is met. If there is no such entry, I want to get a random row. So assuming there is at least one entry in the table, I always want exactly one row returned.

Consider this example table:

```
CREATE TABLE `jukebox` (
    `id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `title` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `lastplayed`    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
);
```

For this example, I want to retrieve the first song that was not played (*lastplayed = 0*). If there is no such song, I'd like to return a random row from the table.

This is what I created so far. It is an ugly monster, and I'm pretty sure it's not very performant.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM jukebox WHERE lastplayed = 0 ORDER BY id DESC)
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM jukebox ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1)
) LIMIT 1
```

I know I can omit the `ORDER BY id DESC` part. I just left it there so it is clear what result I am expecting.

Strangely, I cannot remove the `LIMIT 1` after `RANDOM()`, as I won't get a random result then.

Is there any way to optimize this query?

Comment: "I cannot remove the LIMIT 1 after RANDOM(), as I won't get a random result then." - because the entire construct is ill-defined as UNION does not guarantee order. With the inner LIMIT it has the implementation-defined effect of (appearing to have) an order; aided by the force-materialization of the inner result-set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express your version as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ((SELECT * FROM jukebox WHERE lastplayed = 0 ORDER BY id DESC)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT * FROM jukebox ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1)
      )
     )
ORDER BY lastplayed
LIMIT 1;
```

Or, without the `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM jukebox
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN lastplayed = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         (CASE WHEN lastplayed = 0 THEN id END),
         RANDOM()
LIMIT 1;
```

But, I think this might be better:

```
(SELECT *
 FROM jukebox
 WHERE lastplayed = 0
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
 FROM jukebox
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM jukebox WHERE lastplayed = 0)
 ORDER BY RANDOM()
 LIMIT 1
)
```

It should avoid the sorting when the first subquery already has a match.

Comment: thank you for your queries! I really like the 2nd version because of its shortness, but it does not return the entry with the lowest id if there are several entries with *lastplayed = 0*. Is there an easy way to adapt it to this behvavior? I understand why the third should be an optimal solution, but sqlite refuses to parse it (`near "(": syntax error: `). Maybe it is because of the first parenthesis without prior `SELECT`?

Comment: @muffel . . . Ooops, I had missed that condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think the CASE statement could really simplify this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    jukebox
WHERE
    lastplayed =
        CASE
            WHEN (SELECT MIN(lastplayed) FROM jukebox) = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE lastplayed
        END
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT MIN(lastplayed) FROM jukebox) = 0 THEN id
        ELSE RANDOM()
    END DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I'm not very deep inside the sqlite logic, doesn't your query calculate the minimum *lastplayed* for each entry? The query works, but returns a random result if there are more than one entries having lastplayed = 0 instead of the first one

Comment: My fault, you can add another CASE in the order by. I'll edit my answer

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately sqlite seems unable to parse your new version: `near "DESC": syntax error: `

Comment: Edited to move DESC outside of the case. SQLite's limitations always trip me up because I'm so used to T-SQL.